# Eclipse Java won't Open! "Error has Occured see the log file..."

Tags: java, eclipse

So, this is a problem I've been having with Eclipse recently.

I downloaded it a few nights ago, and launched it successfully the first time, but now it won't load. When I try to open Eclipse it gives me the message

> "Error has occurred, see the log file
>   YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/.log.

I've done quite a bit of research but all I can find doesn't work. I've tried deleting YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/, however, there isn't even a .snap folder in here.

I've also tried downloading java 8 again. Also, I'm on a mac, and a lot of the solutions through command prompt or something are only on Windows.

Please help if you can!

Comment: Did you look in the log file YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/.log like the message suggested?

Comment: What does it actually say in the .log file? If you are using Java 9 the eclipse.ini needs to be modified.